# stay connected to wifi when all users log out

Tags: command-line, wireless, remote-access

When I logout from my session, and no other user is logged locally, the wifi connection is stopped. I would like to keep it on, so that I can log on from a remote computer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit your preferred connection and check:

- Automatically connect to this network
- Available to all users

Also give a high priority number for auto-activation (More than all other connections).

Make sure your wifi gets enabled at boot time (otherwise you have to login and enable it).

Now this connection will be activated before login and stay connected after logout.

#### Using CLI and `nmcli`:

```
nmcli connection modify [CONNECTION-NAME] connection.permissions ''
nmcli connection modify [CONNECTION-NAME] connection.autoconnect yes
nmcli connection modify [CONNECTION-NAME] connection.autoconnect-priority 10
```

#### Using GUI:

[image]

[More info](https://wiki.gnome.org/DarrenAlbers/NetworkManagerFAQ#How_can_I_make_NetworkManager_connect_to_a_network_before_I_login.3F)